# I dont understand something about this piece of code. Hashing

Tags: c#, hash

I don't understand few things in following code. Why the length is set to 16? What is the purpose of the `ret` variable?

Please explain.

I don't understand this:

```
    foreach (byte a in hash)
    {
        if (a < 16)
            ret += "0" + a.ToString("x");
        else
            ret += a.ToString("x");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
if (a < 16) 
    ret += "0" + a.ToString("x"); 
else 
    ret += a.ToString("x");
```

is a worse way of writing

```
ret += a.ToString("x2");
```

Its purpose is to produce a string of length exactly 2 which is the hexadecimal form of the number `a`. Since hex can go up to 15 with just one digit, the code reads "if it would fit in one digit, manually add a zero in front".

Comment: I still don't understand why this needs to be there.

Comment: o.O I had **no** idea you could do that xD. *writes down for use later*.

Comment: I have to imagine this code was ported from some other language, otherwise one would hope the author would use a `StringBuilder` with the `AppendForat` function to build his return value.

Answer (score 6):

This code is getting the hashcode in hexadecimal as string with each byte represented as a 2-digit hexadecimal value - you can do it shorter as:

```
foreach (byte b in hashValue)
   ret +=b.ToString("X2");
```

or better yet use a `StringBuilder` instead:

```
StringBuilder strHash = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in hashValue)
    strHash.Append(b.ToString("X2"));
ret = strHash.ToString();
```

or a little more elegant (but introducing some overhead) using Linq:

```
ret = string.Join("",hashValue.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's just to return the result as an hexadecimal value. If a >= 16, then the hexadecimal value will be two characters long (for instance : A0). IF a < 16, the the hexadecimal value will be one character long (for instance: A), so it's padded with an extra 0 ( => 0A).

Answer (score 3):

Hexadecimal is base 16, so instead of `0123456789` being the available digits, you have `0123456789ABCDEF`. Every byte in a hexedecimal output is represented by 2 digits (16x16 = 256) to avoid ambiguity, so the < 16 check ensures that ToString will output the correct number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

It's converting the byte value to a 2-characters string representation of its hex value. For values < 16 it would output a single character. It's not a very clean way to do it, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`ret` is the value being `ret`urned from the function.